# C# decimal.Parse behaviour

Tags: c#, parsing, decimal

Short question:

Why are these '**.....**' valid for parsing a decimal in .NET (C#):

```
decimal res = decimal.Parse("8......15");  // returns 815
decimal res = decimal.Parse("8...15");     // returns 815
decimal res = decimal.Parse("8..15");      // returns 815
```

What's the reason for this?

Comment: I've check it in .NET4.0. It raise a format exception

Comment: What culture are you using? Those strings can't be parsed using my current culture or the invariant culture.

Comment: I think it's a programmer laziness. I haven't seen a place that uses thousand separator that loosely.

Comment: @Saeed: It depends which culture you're in...

Comment: @Jon skeet, Yes I see your nice answer and upvote it after I left above comment.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It fails for me. Are you by any chance in a culture where "." is the thousands separator and "," is the decimal point? `Decimal.Parse` (and similar calls) use the thread's current culture by default. Whether that is a good thing or not is debatable, but irrelevant to actual behaviour :)

Try specifying `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` in the `decimal.Parse` call:

```
decimal res = decimal.Parse("8......15", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I believe that will behave as you expected.

Comment: I think you've hit the nail on the head there. It parses correctly if you use the `de-DE` culture, for example.

Comment: `es-ES` to. What a weird culture

Comment: Indeed. 
My CurrentCulture is "nl-BE", 
NumberDecimalSeparator = "," and 
NumberGroupSeparator = "."  
 Thanks! But it is rather strange that they allow such notation.

Comment: @juFo: It's certainly odd to support multiple *consecutive* group separators. I dare say there's a reason :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet (reply above) Would be nice if somebody knows the exact reason why this is allowed or supported (I'm referring to the multiple consecutive group separators).

Comment: **The rules are**: 1. first and last chars must be digits. 2. NumberDecimalSeparator - no more than one. 3. NumberGroupSeparator - as many as you like except for rule#1 and not after decimal seperator.

Comment: Is it actually called the 'thousands separator'? Some cultures group digits by ten-thousands.

Comment: @Phil: Some bits of documentation call it the thousands separator; others call it the group separator.

Comment: good point @Phil , might be something to update msdn documentation or make it clear for users.

Comment: @PhilGan Furthermore, there are not-quite-as-regular systems such as the Indian system, 12,34,56,789.  I would probably expect it to validate against the grouping rules of the culture (if any group separators are in the string).  And in any case, not allow multiple consecutive group separators.  And ... no group separators allowed after the decimal separator?  That's a weird rule.

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine it's because the parser doesn't actually care about group separators - they are irrelevant to the process of converting a string to a decimal.

We call them thousands separators, but they're really not. They are group separators - you could split every 3 digits, every 10 digits, every 1 digit, so why not every 0 digits?

Interestingly, the code has changed for .NET 4 - this is the relevant output from Reflector for me:

```
else
{
    if (((currencySymbol == null) || 
         ((chPtr2 = MatchChars(p, currencySymbol)) == null)) && 
        ((ansiCurrencySymbol == null) || 
         ((chPtr2 = MatchChars(p, ansiCurrencySymbol)) == null)))
    {
        break;
    }
    num |= 0x20;
    currencySymbol = null;
    ansiCurrencySymbol = null;
    p = chPtr2 - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know why, but I know how it works (decimal parser code part see below). I think last else if just turn on point flag and skip all points.

```
    while (true)
{
    if (((ch >= '0') && (ch <= '9')) || (((options & NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier) != NumberStyles.None) && (((ch >= 'a') && (ch <= 'f')) || ((ch >= 'A') && (ch <= 'F')))))
    {
        //Here goes some code...
    }
    else if ((((options & NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint) != NumberStyles.None) && ((num & 0x10) == 0)) 
    && (((chPtr2 = MatchChars(p, currencyDecimalSeparator)) != null) || ((flag && ((num & 0x20) == 0)) 
    && ((chPtr2 = MatchChars(p, numberDecimalSeparator)) != null))))
    {
        num |= 0x10;
        p = chPtr2 - 1;
    }
}
```

Use Reflector tool to investigate all code.

Comment: Interesting! Nice to see that part code about the HexSpecifier.